# XML - XSLT - Remove xmlns="" from output XML document

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I have the following XML input document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" 
        repName="FirstElementTemp" 
        date="10-05-2001">
    <element1>
        <subElement>
            SomeData
        </subElement>
    </element1>
    <element2>
        <subElement type="2"/>
    </element2>
</report>
```

And with the following XSLT stylesheet, that user @Mads Hansen helped me to build on a similar post I made yesterday, this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
  xmlns:jsp="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs jsp"
  expand-text="yes"
  version="3.0">


<xsl:param name="doc2"  xmlns="">
    <secondDoc>
    <elementTemps>
        <elemTemp ID="1" name="FirstElementTemp" />
        <elemTemp ID="2" name="SecondTemplate" />
    </elementTemps>
    <elementReps>
        <elemRep tmpID="1" name="FirstElementRep" >
            <value>FIRST DATA</value>
        </elemRep>
        <elemRep tmpID="2" name="SecondTemplate">
            <value>SECOND DATA</value>
        </elemRep>
    </elementReps>
    </secondDoc>     
  </xsl:param>

<xsl:output indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="cDataElement"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="key1" match="elemTemp" use="@name" xpath-default-namespace=""/>
  <xsl:key name="key2" match="elemRep" use="@tmpID" xpath-default-namespace=""/>

 <xsl:template match="report/*[1]">
    <xsl:variable name="temp" select="key('key1', ../@repName, $doc2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rep" select="key('key2', $temp/@ID, $doc2)"/>
    <valueIs>
        <xsl:value-of select="$rep/value" xpath-default-namespace=""/>
    </valueIs>
    <xsl:next-match/>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I was able to get the desired output XML document I wanted, with just one thing wrong. This the the output I'm getting from it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
        repName="FirstElementTemp"
        date="10-05-2001">
    <valueIs xmlns="">FIRST DATA</valueIs>
   <element1>
        <subElement>
            SomeData
        </subElement>
    </element1>
    <element2>
        <subElement type="2"/>
    </element2>
</report>
```

As you can see, the new element I added, `<valueIs>` is coming with the `xmlns=""` attribute. I know that this means that isn't in any namespace, but how can I add that element without the `xmlns` attribute? What do I need to change in the XSLT stylesheet?

So basically this is the output I want, just to be more clear:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
        repName="FirstElementTemp"
        date="10-05-2001">
    <valueIs>FIRST DATA</valueIs>
   <element1>
        <subElement>
            SomeData
        </subElement>
    </element1>
    <element2>
        <subElement type="2"/>
    </element2>
</report>
```

I decided to make a separate post to the one I referenced in the beginning, since this is a different problem,

Thank you!

Alexandre Jacinto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XSLT document is also an XML document, and in that XML document, the `valueIs` element is not in a namespace.

As you want it to be in the `http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports` namespace, just do this...

```
<valueIs xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports">
```

You could add the declaration of this default namespace to the `xsl:stylesheet` element instead, if you wanted, especially if you needed to create other elements elsewhere

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
  xmlns:jsp="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
  xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs jsp"
  expand-text="yes"
  version="3.0">
```

In answer to your `xpath-default-namespace` is an XSLT feature, and only applies to element names in xpath expressions (such as in `select` or `match` attributes) after the XSLT has been parsed as XML.

Comment: "You could add the declaration of this default namespace to the xsl:stylesheet element instead, if you wanted, especially if you needed to create other elements elsewhere". How can I do this? I already have this in the xsl:stylesheet element: xpath-default-namespace="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" . That would suit me, as I need to to create other elements elsewhere

Comment: Thank you so much!